# Monitor multiple Linux log files in real time

Tags: linux, monitoring, logging, tail, realtime

I'm debugging a Linux application that allows remote jobs to be submitted, logging the output from each job in a new file.  The log file paths conform to:

```
/joblogs/job_*/JOB.LOG
```

where the wild card represents the unique job number.

I want to be able to tail each job log, including new logs that are created after I issue the tail (or whatever) command.  I thought I'd be able to do this using [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.html), but I can't figure out the right set of parameters to use.  For example,

```
multitail -q 1 "/joblogs/job_*/JOB.LOG"
```

seems to create a window for each new log file just the way I want, but it doesn't show any output in the file window.

Anyone know how to do this, either with multitail or another Linux tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only one job active at a time, completed job logs are moved to /joblogs/completed_jobs/job_* and the logs are short, this hokey workaround is OK for now:

```
while [ 1 == 1 ] ; do for joblog in `ls /joblogs/job_*/JOB.LOG`; do cat $joblog; done; sleep 10; done
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the parameters and the quotes

Comment: Without the "-q 1", it didn't pick up new files that were created after the multitail command was issued.

Answer (score 0):

like `tail` do you need to give it a `-f` flag to tell it to Follow the files?